# How to use YML values in a config/initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, omniauth

I'm working to integrate facebook in my app. To do that I'm using koala, devise, and omniauth.

For koala, I have

```
/config/facebook.yml

development:
    app_id: 123123132123
    secret_key: dasadsasd1231231
test:
    app_id: 313131313
    secret_key: das132asdads12132
production:
    app_id: dasdsadsadsadsa
    secret_key: adsdsa12das123fds21
```

I then also have with omniauth:

```
/config/initalizers/omniauth.rb

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, 123123132123, 'dasadsasd1231231'
end
```

Problem here is I have the same value repeated in both locations. How can I dry this up so that the app_id and secret_key only live in one place and one file references the other?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a great Railscast on doing this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/85-yaml-configuration-file

In `omniauth.rb`, you can add this line:

```
FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/facebook.yml")[RAILS_ENV]
```

Then you can do:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, FACEBOOK_CONFIG['app_id'], FACEBOOK_CONFIG['secret_key']
end
```

Comment: Helped me with a similar question about S3 config, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305523/rails3-how-to-get-at-aws-s3s-yml-config-data-in-the-app/6306039#6306039, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above answer you might need to use slightly different code to load the file:

```
FACEBOOK_CONFIG = YAML.load_file(Rails.root.join("config","facebook.yml"))[Rails.env]
```